How to reclaim or merge (free space) partition with no identifier in diskutil
After restoring Boot Camp (to remove it), the space hasn't been reclaimed by my AFPS partition and can not be seen in Disk Utility:

The Physical Disk shows the correct size (1.92TB), but the APFS Container (Container 1) doesn't (1.47TB) when selecting each of them in Disk Utility.
Using diskutil list the (free space) is shown, but with no identifier:
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.9 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         1.5 TB     disk0s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data ⁨KRYPTONITE⁩              255.9 MB   disk0s3
                    (free space)                         448.2 GB   -

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1.5 TB     disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨D1 - Data⁩               1.3 TB     disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 300.4 MB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                1.1 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      1.1 MB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨D1⁩                      23.4 GB    disk1s5
   6:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 23.4 GB    disk1s5s1

How to I get my disk space back?
I've restarted twice, run first aid with no issues and read 10+ questions relation to missing partitions after removing Boot Camp, with and without answers and non of them seem to adress this exact situation with no identifier for the free space.
This question seems to be similar, but I have no WINDOWS RECOVERY partition in listed in diskutil, which the accepted answer revolves around.
The KRYPTONITE partition needs to be preserved, so my EGPU is supported in MacOS.
My memory is muddy, but I believe the KRYPTONITE partition was created after the (now deleted) BOOTCAMP partition. If that's of any importance.
I'm running MacOS Monterey 12.6.5.

The free space has to occur immediately after the APPLE_APFS partition in order to merge with the APFS container. You could move the Microsoft Basic Data partition to the end of the drive. Another idea would be to create a new Microsoft Basic Data partition at the end of the drive, then copy the contents of the KRYPTONITE⁩ volume to the new partition. Once finished, you could remove the old partition and merge the free space with the APFS container.

Coolio @DavidAnderson! How do I move the Microsoft Basic Data to the end of the drive?

I solved it by

Erasing the kryptonite container/partition | Kryptonite Uninstallation
choosing the storage device (Aura Pro X2 Media)
choosing »Partition« in the toolbar
deleting KRYPTONITE partition and extending the other partition (D1)
Voilá - it is done!

ps. If you need Kryptonite you can just install it again - which I'll be doing now, thank you!
